# Gstreamer elements memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, gstreamer

How to find memory leak problem in the gstreamer elements/plugins? How to analyse the gst refcount for memory/object leak/refcount? any examples? 
  I am using appsrc and appsink to push and pull buffer to and from the gstreamer pipeline. Seems like there is some memory issue with these elements. I have live source which feeds data to pipeline, typically what are the properties to be set on appsrc and appsink for the live source? 
Thanks-opensid

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like valgrind (memcheck) or asan (address sanitizer) to check for such issues. Refcount issues are tricky to find.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the AppSrc sample then there's a rather easy solution which is to wrap the Gst.Buffer allocation in a using statement.

E.G. Change the following method

```
static void PushAppData (object o, Gst.App.NeedDataArgs args) {
  ulong mseconds = 0;
  if (appsrc.Clock != null)
    mseconds = appsrc.Clock.Time / Clock.MSecond;
  Gst.Buffer buffer = DrawData (mseconds);
  appsrc.PushBuffer (buffer);
}
```

to this

```
static void PushAppData (object o, Gst.App.NeedDataArgs args) {
  ulong mseconds = 0;
  if (appsrc.Clock != null)
    mseconds = appsrc.Clock.Time / Clock.MSecond;
  using(Gst.Buffer buffer = DrawData (mseconds))
    appsrc.PushBuffer (buffer);
}
```

Previously for my this sample would crash in <30 seconds. Now it runs until I kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Valgrind tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html)

see this sample:
http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/